# Select text in TypeScript

Tags: html, typescript, select

how can I select text in input field in TypeScript.

in Javascript this wpuld look like this:

```
document.getElementById('id').select();
```

but TypeScript does not support select (error: [ts] Property 'select' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.)

Added a few think:
It may be a problem beacouse I use dx controls and they create a wraper. You can see here in html:

```
<dx-text-box _ngcontent-c1="" id="test" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-value="0:00" class="dx-texteditor dx-widget dx-textbox">
<div class="dx-texteditor-container">
<input autocomplete="off" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="textbox">
<div data-dx_placeholder="" class="dx-placeholder dx-state-invisible"></div><div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
</div></div></dx-text-box>
```

Comment: I found a solution       (document.getElementById('id').getElementsByTagName('input')[0] as HTMLInputElement).select();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`document.getElementById(string)` returns an `HTMLElement` which does not define a `select()` method. `HTMLInputElement` DOES define a `select()` method and also extends `HTMLElement`, so if you cast as `HTMLInputElement`, it should work:

```
 (document.getElementById('id') as HTMLInputElement).select();
```

Comment: This should work if I had just Input element.

Comment: Thank you! this solved my problem too

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the result of `document.getElementById()` to a more specific type, in this case `HTMLInputElement`:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('id')).select();
// or (TSX-friendly)
(document.getElementById('id') as HTMLInputElement).select();
```

This is allowed, since `HTMLInputElement` extends `HTMLElement`, adding the properties such as `select` that don't exist on all types of HTML element.